# How to add styles to react-pdf Document

Tags: reactjs, styling, react-pdf

1. **I tried with this code and cannot adjust the width**

   ```
                           <Document
                               style={{width:"100px"}}
                               file="123.pdf"
                               onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}
                           >
                               <Page pageNumber={pageNumber} />
                           </Document>
   ```

Comment: try adding background color and check whether styles are actually being added or not

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-pdf

Comment: style={{}} was not working. react-pdf has no width property. But there was a height property. I used that and according to ratio it adjusted the width as well.

Answer (score 0):

style={{}} was not working. react-pdf has no width property. But there was a **height** property. I used that and according to ratio it adjusted the width as well. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation https://react-pdf.org/components  does not support style, you need to style the **page** component

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove (px) keep as a number or string without px => width: "100" or width: 100

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33086029)